# Lenovo B50 OS windows7 need USB to boot every time

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bios, bootloader

I am facing a strange problem. I installed Windows 7 on my laptop (From DVD) after installation system did not boot just Lenovo and the black screen again and again.

I re-installed Windows from a bootable USB. Now I have to use my USB to boot  every time. Without USB System the boot failed.

How my system automatically boot from my harddrive?

I already tried `diskpart`, `bootsect`, `bootrec`, `/fixmbr`, `/fixboot` `/rebuildbcd`, etc. but no result.

Comment: Try a newer OS. If the PC is 32-bit, I'd recommend Linux, e.g., Ubuntu 18.04. Windows 7 is not supported, any longer. See https://itsfoss.com/32-bit-os-list/

Comment: I agree in general but that machine came with Windows 8 so I thought Windows 7 might install. I haven’t yet nailed down the error

Comment: @DrMoish I Just installed the windows 10 . Problem is Still there.

Comment: 1. How did you make the Windows 10 USB? Use the Media Creation Tool, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/  and reinstall. 2. Did you wipe the HDD? If so, you may need a new, licensed, copy of Win 10.

Comment: @DrMoishe . Problem is that HDD not ACT as BOOTABLE Device. Please Help